# Python's winsound.Beep() pause issues

Tags: python, beep

So my code is as such:

```
import winsound
import time

length = 250

class Notes():
    def frequency(halfNotesFromA4):
        value = 440 * ((2)**(1.0/12.0))**halfNotesFromA4
        return (int)(value)
    def processNote(note):
        if(note == 'C'):return Notes.frequency(3)
        if(note == 'D'):return Notes.frequency(5)
        if(note == 'E'):return Notes.frequency(7)
        if(note == 'F'):return Notes.frequency(8)
        if(note == 'G'):return Notes.frequency(10)
        if(note == 'A'):return Notes.frequency(12)
        if(note == 'B'):return Notes.frequency(14)

song = "EDCDEEE"
noteList = list(song)
print(noteList)

for note in noteList:
    print("Doing ", note)
    frequency = Notes.processNote(note)
    winsound.Beep(frequency, length)
```

It works fine but the problem I'm having is there is a pause between each beep. I was hoping to play the sound continuously without pauses so that it sounds like real music. Is this possible with the winsound.Beep() library?

Comment: Maybe the `ASYNC` flag can help: http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC Btw.: shouldn't your notes be Notes.frequency(n) with n = [3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14]?

Comment: the frequency method returns a rounded version of the frequency set from A4(440hz) so it returns the correct value. Also I'm looking up the ASYNC flag you are talking bout'

Comment: But you cannot take half note steps to get a major scale. E.g. from C to D there's a full note step.

Comment: Ah lol. Your right, Notes.frequency(5) would be D not E! Silly me. Also I cannot see how the asynchronous flag would cause the Beep to play right after the last beep : (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

even if you use a while loop like this:

```
 import winsound

 while True:
    winsound.Beep(100, 100)
```

there is still a small pause between and it wont sound like a solid note and you cant get much faster than that

You can still try it but i dont think you can get it to just sound like one long beep but winsound does have `winsound.PlaySound(sound, flags)` so you can load a sound here are the [Winsound Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html)

something you could do is use [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) it will be more work but it is probably a much better way to create music

you can use [Pygame Music](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) to load and play the music and im sure you could make it much more interactive the thing is you have to load each sound from a file

if you dont want to do all that take a look at [Python In Music](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) thats probably a good place to start

Comment: I noticed that winsound had that pause no matter how I played around with it : ( I just wanted to put my code up for someone to help just in case (As Johannes Charra did), I could have put an easier example like yours too. I was hoping not to have to resort to a different library but I'll look into the one you mentioned!