# How to play the sound in background while the text is being dynamically displayed in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to play the beep sound continuously till the text is being displayed dynamically on the terminal. Here goes my code.

```
import time
import sys
import winsound


winsound.Beep(1000, 5000)

def printf(s):

    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write('%s' % c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.0203)

printf("Hello I am Jishan Bhattacharya.")
```

Comment: That smells like multithreading, resp multiprocessing if first does not work, you can execute beep as another thread with writing text, so they wil be executed in paralel, [multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html). Multithreading is simpler but there is possibility that it did not work because of pythons GIL (python can't actualy use threads, only fast switch execution paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something like this, but my testing showed my that you cann't use it with Beep.You could save the sound as a wav file,instead.

```
winsound.PlaySound(sound, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread and start running it, create a bool to stop thread [though this will cause little pauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423267/pythons-winsound-beep-pause-issues).

There is no apparent way to use beep and make it stop dynamically.

```
import threading

class beeper(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.keeprunning = True
        while self.keeprunning:
            winsound.Beep(freq, dur) // make a short dur to make sure it stops soon after printing ends
beep =  beeper()
beep.start()
printf(string)
beep.keeprunning = False
```

Comment: Please edit 'winsound.beep' to 'winsound.Beep'. I tried your code but the thing is that the beep continued also after the text is being finished displaying.

Comment: Added a stop clause, make duration short so it verifies it should run often

Comment: Tried your code but this time it's printing the text dynamically infinite number of times and there's occurring an interrupt too between beeps which seems weird.